# Can I return a view from a class in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, class, view

I'm new in c# and mvc3 so it might be quite a stupid question:
I need to show the Error.cshtml view whenever an error message is sent to the log file.

I don't want to write each time to return the view. That's why I created a class (called "CatchError") that is called automatically when any error is sent.

For example- I want to show the view if the status is not "True" in the following case:

```
if(status == "true")
  LogMessageFM.SuccessMessage("Feature Management success:" + userid + "/" + features + "/" + shape + "/" + lab + "/" + priceList);
else
  LogMessageFM.UnsuccessMessage("Feature Management unsuccess:" + userid + "/" + features + "/" + shape + "/" + lab + "/" + priceList);
```

Can I return the view from the class?
  Or should I create a new ActionResult that will get the error and return the view with the error??

(But then, how can I cause it run automatically...Is there such an option?)

I'll be very glad to get some help. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. You want to show the error page when an unhandled exception is thrown?

Comment: There are a few places in the controllers where an error is sent to a log file. Then I want to show the view with the error (the same error that sent to the log file).

Comment: But in what situation does this happen in your controllers? When an exception is thrown? Could you provide an example of a controller action where you are writing to the log file?

Comment: I added an example to the question,

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure as long as the return type is ActionResult you can return the view.  by default if you're creating a class for say like an object and you don't have system.web.mvc you'll have to reference it in your file, but other than that you should be good.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public ActionResult CatchError()
{
     if(LogicFails)
     {
         return View();
     }
     else
    {
         RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

of course, because you're returning an ActionResult you'll have to eventually return some URL, but essentially all you're saying is when this is executed make an HTTP Request to this URL.

In short yes, hope this helps!

Happy Coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurs in your code and you've got an appropriate `customErrors` tag in your web.config, then the URL mentioned in `defaultRedirect` will be displayed:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/500" />
```

You can then have a route which points that URL (`/Error/500`) to your given view.

[MSDN article on customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)

**Updated after question below**

The `defaultRedirect` value can point anywhere. So if you already have a 'CatchError' action in your 'Home' controller, you could just do this:-

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Home/CatchError" />
```

This means that if you are able to catch the error in a `try catch` block for example, you can redirect the user to your CatchError action. And if you DON'T catch the exception, your users will automatically be sent there anyway.

Comment: Sorry about the question, but how can I change the "500" in the route?